# Opening a new WSL2 tab in Windows terminal and executing command

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-terminal

I'm using WSL2 on Windows terminal. I have an app that needs front end and backend booted before it can be used, so every time I nave to open a terminal window, navigate to a folder and run a command.
I would like to set an alias that would open a new tab, navigate to a folder and do go run .
I saw suggestions for linux, but none of those work on Windows Terminal with WSL2. Anyone have experience with this setup?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a profile for this. Something like

```json
{
    "commandline": "wsl.exe -d Ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8",
    "name": "backend",
    "startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\zadjii\\path\\to\\project",
},
```

(of course, replace `ping 8.8.8.8` with the actual command you want to run, replace `Ubuntu` with the name of the distro you're using, and replace `home\\zadjii\\path\\to\\project` with your actual path, delimited by double-backslashes.)

Now, if you wanted to get really crazy, you could create an action in the [Command Palette](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-palette) which opened up multiple commands all at once:

```json
{ 
    "name": "Run my project", 
    "command": { 
        "action": "multipleActions",
        "actions": [
            // Create a new tab with two panes
            { "action": "newTab", "tabTitle": "backend", "commandline": "wsl.exe -d Ubuntu run_my_backend", "startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\zadjii\\path\\to\\backend" },
            { "action": "splitPane", "tabTitle": "frontend", "commandline": "wsl.exe -d Ubuntu run_my_frontend", "startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\zadjii\\path\\to\\frontend" },
        ]
    }
}
```

see [`multipleActions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#run-multiple-actions)